# How to find the number of Jobs in SQL Server Agent Jobs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Do we have a  way to find the number of jobs  currently in SQL Server Agent and there names. I can count manually but  i am looking  for a script to give me the  number  and names.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return `n` rows, and their names:

```
SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs;
```